Is this is right way to implement Thirdweb authentication with saving user in our backend database if user not present
// UserLoginProvider.js
export const UserLoginProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [walletAddress, setWalletAddress] = useState("");
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserLoggedIn = async () => {
      let isLogin = await isLoggedIn();
      setLoggedIn(isLogin);
    };
    getUserLoggedIn();
  }, [walletAddress]);

  // ... other state and functions

  return (
    <UserLoginContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </UserLoginContext.Provider>
  );
};

// ConnectBtn.js
export default function ConnectBtn() {
  // ... state and functions from useUserLogin()
const {
    setWalletAddress,
    setIsLoading,
    setIsError,
    setWallet,
    connectButtonRef,
    setLoggedIn,
  } = useUserLogin();
  const { disconnect } = useDisconnect();
  const { refetchProducts } = useProducts();
  const clientBackend = {
    clientId: "d41dd66624d7e93e047a1285c00e9dd2",
    secretKey: undefined,
  };

  const saveInDatabaseHandler = async (
    walletAddress: string,
    wallet: Wallet
  ) => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const email = await getUserEmail({ client: clientBackend });
      if (!email) {
        disconnect(wallet);
      }
      const payload = {
        email: email,
        wallet_address: walletAddress,
      };
      const response = await CreateUserService(payload);
      if (response && response.token) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.token);
      }
      setWalletAddress(walletAddress);
      setWallet(wallet);
      await refetchProducts();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setIsError(true);
      disconnect(wallet);
    } finally {
      setWalletAddress("");
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleDisconnect = async () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    setWalletAddress("");
    setIsLoading(false);
    setWallet(null);
    await refetchProducts();
  };
  return (
    <ConnectButton
      // ... configuration props
      auth={{
        isLoggedIn: async (address) => {
          let userLoggedIn = await isLoggedIn();
          return userLoggedIn;
        },
        doLogin: async (params) => {
          await login(params);
        },
        getLoginPayload: async ({ address }) => generatePayload({ address }),
        doLogout: async () => {
          await logout();
        },
      }}
      onConnect={async (wallet) => {
        const acc = wallet.getAccount();
        await saveInDatabaseHandler(acc.address, wallet);  //This request will go to the backend first to generate the user if user is not present.
      }}
      onDisconnect={handleDisconnect}
    />
  );
}

Is this approach of combining Thirdweb's ConnectButton with custom authentication logic (including server-side checks and a separate database for user management) a valid and recommended way to implement user login and wallet connection in a Thirdweb-based application? Are there any potential issues or best practices we should be aware of when implementing this pattern?
Its working but sometimes giving , 429 too many embedded Third web calls, and producing too many request error from sentry.
